# CSS Grid auto width issue

Tags: css, css-grid

## Issue description

I created a simple grid with 3 areas. The last area extends to the entire grid. And I want this area not to affect the auto width behavior for first and second areas.

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item item--1">ooo</div>
    <div class="item item--2">ooo</div>
    <div class="item item--3">oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo ooooooo ooooooo ooooooo</div>
</div>
```

```css
.item--1 {
  grid-area: a1;
}
.item--2 {
  grid-area: a2;
}
.item--3 {
  grid-area: a3;
}

.grid {
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a1 a2"
    "a3 a3";
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can see in the screen that the last area brake auto width behavior if it contains long content:
[image]

How to solve this issue using CSS only?

## Test and reproduce

I tested it in Chrome 96.0.4664.45

You can see and reproduce this issue [in CodePen](https://codepen.io/mitani-kun/pen/MWEwZpa), or in code  snipped below:

```css
.tests {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.grids {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.item--1 {
  grid-area: a1;
}
.item--2 {
  grid-area: a2;
}
.item--3 {
  grid-area: a3;
}

.grid {
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a1 a2"
    "a3 a3";
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="tests">
  <div class="test">
    <div class="title">Normal behavior:</div>
    <div class="grids">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="test">
    <div class="title">Issue (the second row broke auto width):</div>
    <div class="grids">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo ooooooo ooooooo ooooooo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo ooooooo ooooooo ooooooo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo ooooooo ooooooo ooooooo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo ooooooo ooooooo ooooooo</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you put the examples into a working snippet into your question as I cannot reproduce the right hand image. If I put a very long unbreakable string into the second area then it minimises the first div so it looks like the top right section of your 'normal behavior'  image.

Comment: @a-haworth see example here: https://codepen.io/mitani-kun/pen/MWEwZpa
I tested it in Chrome 96.0.4664.45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `width:0;min-width:100%;` on the `.item--3`. The item will not contribute to the width calculation (`width:0`) but will keep a full width behavior (`min-width:100%`)

```css
.tests {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.grids {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.item--1 {
  grid-area: a1;
}
.item--2 {
  grid-area: a2;
}
.item--3 {
  grid-area: a3;
  width:0;
  min-width:100%;
}

.grid {
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a1 a2"
    "a3 a3";
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="tests">
  <div class="test">
    <div class="title">Normal behavior:</div>
    <div class="grids">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="test">
    <div class="title">Issue (the second row broke auto width):</div>
    <div class="grids">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo ooooooo ooooooo ooooooo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo ooooooo ooooooo ooooooo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">ooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo ooooooo ooooooo ooooooo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item--1">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--2">oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
        <div class="item item--3">oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo oooooooo ooooooo ooooooo ooooooo</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This is an interesting CSS magic, I didn’t know about it. I tested this solution in Chrome Latest, Firefox Latest, Edge Latest and Safari 11 - it works everywhere.